# Is it safe to use this AWS Lambda policy role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In IAM roles that are assigned to lambda function I was using this policy but it was returning "Access Denied".

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::__YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE__/*"    
    }
  ]
}
```

=========================================

## I changed Resource to " * " and it works. is it safe to use " * " ??

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not only you've changed `Resource`, you also put `*` in `Action`. It's not safe, but what was the problem in the first place. Did you Lambda fail to deploy? Did your Lambda fail to execute? Where is that `Access Denied` coming from? Could you provide source code for your Lambda?

Comment: Silly question... you did replace `__YOUR_BUCKET_NAME_HERE__` with your bucket name, e.g. `"arn:aws:s3:::my-example-bucket/*"`, correct?  This is just the bucket name, it is case-sensitive, and needs the `/*` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you try to get the initial policy working.

The new permissions allow the Lambda function to perform *any* operation in Amazon S3 against *all* buckets in the account.

If you are the only person operating this account, then that's fine. However, if you wish to control access to resources that other users can use, they could take advantage of this role to do actions that they normally wouldn't be able to perform.